# PHP File write function not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a website. It has this function:

```
public static function createPost($postName,$user,$content) {
    echo "Posting...";
    $dir = fopen(storage_path('app/posts.xml'), "r+");
    $contents = fread($dir,filesize(storage_path('app/posts.xml')));
    echo $contents;
    $contents = str_replace('</posts>', '', $dir);
    fwrite($dir,$contents);
    fclose($dir);
    $file = fopen(storage_path('app/posts.xml'), "a") or die("<h1>500 Server Error.</h1>");
    fwrite($file,"<post>\n");
    fwrite($file,'<postname><div id="postname">'.$postName.'</div>
</postname>\n');
    fwrite($file,"<div></div>");
    fwrite($file,"<user>By ".$user."</user>\n");
    fwrite($file,"<div></div>");
    fwrite($file,"<content>".$content."</content>\n");
    fwrite($file,"</post>\n");
    fwrite($file,"</posts>\n");
    fclose($file);
    echo "<script>window.location.assign('/home.php');</script>";
}
```

But, when I run it, it didn't replace the  with '' (line 6). Instead it return a strange string

> Resource id #188

The file is exist. So why it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to do a str_replace on this Resource(not on the text itself):

```
$dir = fopen(storage_path('app/posts.xml'), "r+");
```

According to the PHP manual located at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php the return value can be a file pointer resource on success or FALSE on error.

Try to replace $dir with $contents like this:

```
$contents = str_replace('</posts>', '', $contents);
```